# Ruby script run with C uses the wrong version

Tags: c, ruby

I'm working on Raspbian which comes with 1.9.1 installed. I used RVM to install 2.1.2 and then proceeded to install several gems, all of which installed under 2.1.2.

When I run `ruby -v` I get 2.1.2. However, when I have a C program run a Ruby script it gives me an error telling me it can't find required gems and it also tells me where it's looking, which is in the 1.9.1 folder.

Why is this happening? How do I force C to use 2.1.2?

Comment: How are you calling the script? Can you show the C code? This may be a shell/environment issue.

Comment: It'd really help if you show a minimal version of how you're launching script. There are lots of ways to get there and, as is, we don't know which path you're using.

Comment: It's just `system("ruby scriptname.rb")`